# How best to deal with factually incorrect accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

If someone posts an answer that is factually incorrect one can point this out in a comment on the answer and, if one feels so inclined, add one’s own answer. Another alternative would be to edit the answer, if only part of it is incorrect. When an answer containing a major error has been accepted (because of the poster’s ignorance) it seems to me more important to edit the answer, rather than provide one of one’s own. Is that allowed / recommended?

Comment: Good question which highlights the problem of using voting to determine fact. I think the only reasonable solution is to down vote and comment. Posting your own answer would also help.